# can we use app only auth for getting twiiter trends in android

Tags: android, twitter-oauth

can we use app only authentication for getting twitter trends in android
please help me

im getting the error bad authenticatio error 215

heres my code

i just need to know about the oauth

**Auth Activity Class**

```
package com.tmm.android.twitter;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import twitter4j.http.BASE64Encoder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;



public class AuthActivity extends Activity {    

private Button buttonLogin;

String bearer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_oauth);



    //Define login button and listener
    buttonLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonLogin);
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        public void onClick(View v) {


            try {
                askOAuth();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                getjson();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




        }
    });
}


public void askOAuth() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token");

    final String APIKEY = "Y0VtCZrmBYFAlMOIjzU4w";                         //Consumer 
    final String APISECRET = "6iYDIgTJjUjfx4RJ2zMkrrLY6tvI0F4oobRcFWdTk";  //Consumer Secret

    String apiString = APIKEY + ":" + APISECRET;


    String authorization = "Basic " + BASE64Encoder.encode(apiString.getBytes()).toString();

    Log.d("auth authorization",authorization);

    httppost.setHeader("Authorization", authorization);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    Log.d("auth response",httpclient.execute(httppost).toString());

    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response =  httpclient.execute(httppost);

    //Log.d(" auth entity",response.getEntity().toString());

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    //Log.d("auth entitycontent",entity.getContent().toString());

    inputStream = entity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    bearer=sb.toString();



}

public  void getjson() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, org.json.JSONException
{

    //JSONArray jarray;

    Gson gson =new Gson();

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1");
    httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "bearer");
    httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    Log.d("auth response",httpclient.execute(httpget).toString());

    org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    //Log.d(" auth entity",response.getEntity().toString());

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    //Log.d("auth entitycontent",entity.getContent().toString());

    inputStream = entity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
     sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    Log.e("sb", sb.toString());

    TwitterTrends objs=gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), TwitterTrends.class);

    Log.e("MY INFO", ""+objs.getTrends().size());
    for(TwitterTrend tr : objs.getTrends()){
        Log.d("TRENDS NAME", tr.getName());
    }

}
}
```

ive twiiter trends class and twitter trend class

dont worry about the gson part

im getting the error bad authenticatio error 215

Answer (score 0):

What you aren't doing is making the user login to his twitter account. Make sure the user gets logged in first. The login - piece of code will verify the signatures and only then your bad authentication error will be removed.